# Jquery: Number the occurance of equivalent class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a short question.

If i have multiple divs with same class name:

```
<div class="apple">Sweet </div>
<div class="apple">Healty </div>
<div class="apple">Nice </div>
```

How can I number the class according to their Occurance?

**For Example,**

If I hover over **Sweet**, 1 should be alerted. Likewise, if i hover over **Nice**, 3 should be alerted.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Dei Sushang, are you there?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below using `index()` function.

```
$('.apple').hover(function(){
    alert($(this).index()+1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `index()`:

```
$('.apple').hover(function(){
    alert($(this).text() + " " + $(this).index())
});
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$('.apple').hover(function(){
  alert($(this).text() + " " + $(this).index())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apple">Sweet </div>
<div class="apple">Healty </div>
<div class="apple">Nice </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `index` method and [mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event

```
$(".apple").mouseenter(function(){

   alert($(this).index() + 1);

});
```